# The training results of YOLOv5 are marked incorrectly

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

I am a beginner in YOLOv5, and I am training a custom model. 
I used Roboflow to create a dataset, which includes a Training Set with 2,000 images, a Validation Set with 183 images, and a Testing Set with 115 images. 
The results I get from training are not satisfactory, as seen in the image below, the position of the cueball is always significantly off. I don't know why this is happening and I am wondering if there are any ways to improve this.

**result1**
[image: result1] \

**result2**
[image: result2]

This is the command I use during training. 
`python train.py --img 416 --batch 32 --epochs 500 --data data.yaml --weights yolov5l.pt --cache`

I have tried using other YOLOv5 models, but the results are still the same. I have also continuously added data to my dataset, but there has been no improvement in the results. I would like to ask if anyone knows whether I should continue training or if there are other methods to improve the results?

The following are some indicator data about the dataset. Although I have 5 classes, I only used two of them, cue and cueball, during training.
[image: Class Balance]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the cue ball is actually pretty spot on. If you notice the bounding box for the actual cue has a high confidence (0.76) for result 1 and 0.82 for result 2. And the rest are detections with low confidence. Judging from those two images, i guess that your recall is very high, but your precision is a bit low. You can apply a higher threshold (basically saying to filter out the ouputs under a certain confidence). You can set a default threshold of 0.5, and see if it works for your use case or not, then decrease it or increase it depending on what you want.

Comment: The performance of the cue stick is good, that's for sure. Perhaps I didn't describe it clearly enough - what I meant was the performance of the cueball. As shown in the first picture, there is no indication of where the cue ball is located.

Comment: Can you share your metrics for all your classes? and in your training dataset, how many instances of cue/cueball do you have?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the relevant information in the article. However, I am not quite sure what "metrics" means. If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's exactly what you provided. Your model seems to be struggling with your "cueball" class. Judging from the images you've shared so far, I can guess that it's an annotation issue / mismatch between the training set and validation set images view angle. Make sure that all the instances of "cueball" have bounding boxes that are tightly close to the object. Also make sure that you have the right balance of images on your training and validation set.

Comment: If all your training images that contain cueball are taking from a vertical point of view, but your validation images are taking from a horizontal point of view, then your model will struggle with that class.  Also try adding some blurring preprocessing steps, in the first image the cueball is blurred mostly due to its movement. The cueball in the second image has a higher confidence where it was stationary.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for your help. I have another question: if I update the data set, should I retrain my existing model or train a new one to improve the performance?

Comment: In this case, it's better to re-train the model from the start. If you observe that your training and validation loss are still decreasing, then you can increase the number of epochs to improve performance.

Comment: Ok I see.Thank you very much for your patient assistance. I will try the method you suggested and thank you again.

Comment: I have solved the problem as you suggested. I made each label more precise and now it can function properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: No need, glad to have helped!